# Docker unsupported manifest mediatype

Tags: docker

Error when running docker pull/run on many image types. Here is just one example.

```
docker run --rm -it -p 4040:4040 gettyimages/spark bin/run-example SparkPi 10

ERRO[63011] Handler for POST /v1.22/containers/create returned error: No such image: gettyimages/spark:latest 
Unable to find image 'gettyimages/spark:latest' locally
ERRO[63011] Handler for POST /v1.22/images/create returned error: unsupported manifest mediatype: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v1+prettyjws 
docker: Error response from daemon: unsupported manifest mediatype: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v1+prettyjws.
```

docker version

```
Client:
 Version:      1.10.0-rc1
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   677c593
 Built:        Fri Jan 15 18:17:17 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.10.0-rc1
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   677c593
 Built:        Fri Jan 15 18:17:17 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Comment: Where is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update docker; you're running a release candidate of docker 1.10.0. Update to the latest release (1.10.3), which contains various fixes since the first release candidate